# IIS6 Error 504 400 0 64

Tags: iis-6

The problem occurs when working on sitecore content editor. When a user takes some action, internet explorer freezes and after a while it shows

```
 ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.
```

When I am connected to our hosting servers through VPN connection it works fine. Any help in debugging this is greatly appreciated.

**From IIS Logs**

2010-07-14 06:29:14 W3SVC1515735300 x.x.x.85 POST /en/sitecore/shell/sitecore/content/Applications/Content+Editor.aspx ic=People%2f16x16%2fcubes_blue.png&he=Content+Editor&cl=0 80 - x.x.x.58 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+InfoPath.3) 400 0 64

**From HTTPERR Logs**
2010-07-14 06:29:14 x.x.x.58 50955 x.x.x.85 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /en/sitecore/shell/sitecore/content/Applications/Content+Editor.aspx?ic=People%2f16x16%2fcubes_blue.png&he=Content+Editor&cl=0 - 1515735300 Timer_EntityBody DefaultAppPool

**Analyzing traffic with Fiddler shows the following Url causes the freeze**

Fiddler
http://x.x.x.85/en/sitecore/shell/sitecore/content/Applications/Content%20Editor.aspx?ic=People%2f16x16%2fcubes_blue.png&he=Content+Editor&cl=0
504  ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.

Answer (score 1):

Is the IP address only accessible via the VPN? What routes does the VPN provide?

Maybe the VPN is required to edit content based on the way your provider has set up their service?

Comment: Agreed: If changing the network path produces a different result, you should be troubleshooting the network path. Simultaneous traces on client and server (and perhaps a comparative trace with the VPN connected for the "working" case) should help idenfify whether stuff's getting lost in transit.